# CSS for IE11 filter

Tags: css, filter, internet-explorer-11

I need to use filter on an svg image to change the colour but it does not work on IE.

I have looked and seen that this is because it is not supported but I need another way to do this. I need to change the colour, fill is not an option. Is there a way to get filter to work on IE?

filter: brightness(0) saturate(100%) invert(100%) sepia(0%) saturate(25%) hue-rotate(70deg) brightness(108%) contrast(108%);

Comment: Basically...no. It's just not supported.

Comment: Is there another way around this to do it? I have said I know it doesn't work, I need to find a solution. Whether that is another way or not.

Comment: Quite simply...there isn't one.

Comment: So is the only solution I have to upload separate svgs?

Comment: Seems likely but I don't know how you are implementing all this. I'm unsure what `fill` isn't an option for an inline SVG.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't use filter with CSS in IE11, as a workaround you could use [SVG filter markup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/filter). The [CSS filter function and its equivalent SVG filter markup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Functions) is listed in MDN. But the display sometimes is a little different when using the SVG filter markup, you can also see that in the examples in MDN.

I make a example which equals the css style `filter: invert(100%)`, it can work in IE11:

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" id="svg-filter" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <filter id="invert">
            <feComponentTransfer>
                <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="1 0" />
                <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="1 0" />
                <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="1 0" />
            </feComponentTransfer>
        </filter>
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" filter="url(#invert)" />
</svg>
```

For more information, you could also refer to [this article](https://www.broken-links.com/2013/11/20/cross-browser-filters-css-svg/).